# Can you add a column to a form list library, without modifying the form template or displaying it to the form template?

Tags: form, template

We have a form template developed with SharePoint Developer.  We want to add a column / field to the form library, but not the form.  Is this possible without modifying the form template?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the new field and it will not affect your form. Keep in mind the field should not be marked as Required.

If required field then the Form submit will fail.